# Terraform Azure Stream Analytics Job - Start/Stop

Tags: terraform, azure-stream-analytics, azure-rm

I have a stream analytics job defined in terraform, but if changes are made to the job and it's currently running, `terraform apply` fails. Is there a way to detect changes to the job in terraform, and if there are any, stop the job and then restart the job after `apply` is done?

I could run a powershell script to stop and start it on `apply`, but would like to avoid stopping/starting the job every time apply is run if possible. I was looking at [this](https://markgossa.blogspot.com/2019/04/run-powershell-from-terraform.html) article, but it doesn't look like it would work in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Looking for the same thing! I am thinking of using some extra steps to start and stop the stream analytics job. For this, you will need to have the az cli installed on the system you are using for the provisioning. I will update my answer when things are working.

Update: I found a method that works, although I would like to see Terraform manage this on its own. I use Github actions, but these steps can be applied in any environment:

```
# Stop the job, so it can be updated.
# Do not fail when job does not exist.
az stream-analytics job stop \
  --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> \
  --name <JOB_NAME> || true

# Apply changes
terraform apply

# Start the job again
az stream-analytics job start \
  --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP> \
  --name <JOB_NAME> \
  --output-start-mode LastOutputEventTime
```

Caution, do not forget `--output-start-mode LastOutputEventTime`, this means the job will start processing from the time it was stopped. Otherwise, the unprocessed events within the window you are updating could be lost.

Comment: What happens if terraform apply fails ?